# php get video from file_get_contents('php://input')

Tags: javascript, php, web-worker

I'm trying to upload a video with some other parameters via a shared web worker.

Here below I paste de code I'm using:

**record.js**

```
function sendVideo(name, path) {    
    var worker = new SharedWorker("js/upload.js");

    worker.port.postMessage([path, name + '.webm', blob]);

    // worker.port.start();

    worker.port.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('Message received from worker ' + e.data);
    }
}
```

**upload.js**

```
onconnect = function(e) {

  var port = e.ports[0];

  port.onmessage = function(e) {
      var path = e.data[0];
      var fileName = e.data[1];
      var video = e.data[2];
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      request.open('POST', 'http://localhost/channel/upload', true);

      request.onload = function () {
          port.postMessage(request.responseText);
      };

      request.send('fileName=' + fileName + '&video=' + video);
  }

  // port.start();  // not necessary since onmessage event handler is being used
}
```

**channel.php**

```
public function upload()
{
  $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
  // get the video from $data and move it
}
```

The problem is if my worker send:

`request.send('fileName=' + fileName + '&video=' + video);`

the content that my php code get is [blob data].

and if my worker send:

```
request.send('video=' + video);
```

the content that my php get is the video coded, full of special characters.

My question is how could I get the text and the video like if I had `$_FILES` in order to process it correctly.

Thanks in advice.